# Is there a way to store class instances into a database? Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm currently looking for a way to store class instances within a database, specifically an sqlite3 one. I know that class instances can be stored within lists, as an example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo1 = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.foo1 += 1

foo = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()

foo_list = []

print(foo.foo1) # 0
foo.increment()
print(foo.foo1) # 1

foo_list.append(foo)
foo_list.append(foo2)

print(foo_list) # [<__main__.Foo object at 0x000001A53B3AD4E0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001A53B3AD810>] <- the desired output
```

But the problem is: lists are temporary in the sense that they're cleared once the script is offline - and I'm working with a bot, which is prone to being taken down for maintenance at any given moment; I don't want to keep initializing those instances each time I bring my bot down for maintenance.

What I'd like is for my database to supply me with something like `<__main__.Foo object at 0x000001A53B3AD4E0>` when queried, an instance which I can make modifications to and be able to check any current values within this instance which have been modified in the past.

Any help would greatly suffice, and please do supply some code with any helpful responses :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you store the class instances rather than build a table that models your data, and then you can serialize/deserialize the data back and forth between (database/json/etc.)?

Comment: Never even thought this would be possible. Waiting to see a good answer.

Comment: You're looking for serialization. It's a pretty well hashed out thing. There are pickle files, JSON files, and any other format you care to use. That being said, you need to do a bunch more research to figure out what you really want.

Comment: Could you pickle the class?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well hashed out… is that a pun?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. SO is not the place to teach serialization concepts from scratch, but hopefully the comments gave you enough info to get started

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine. No, but it could be :)

Comment: There's a standard module for this apparently: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html. TIL.

Comment: Add "persistent storage" to your search terms

Comment: One option is to use an Object Relational Mapping such as `sqlalchemy`. This won't store a class object directly, but it can serialize and deserialize an object from fields in a table.

Comment: pickle is a security risk because it runs code on deserialization.  just because it's your data doesn't mean someone can't mod the file without your knowledge and then cause you to run random stuff with your privileges later.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183966/safely-load-a-pickle-file#:~:text=Warning%20The%20pickle%20module%20is%20not%20secure%20against,able%20to%20exectue%20arbitrary%20code%20on%20your%20system.

Comment: @JLPeyret I was about to comment that, pickle is good; but that's my current concern with it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning about Object Relational Mapping libraries such as `sqlalchemy`. This won't store the instance directly, but instead store fields of the instance as columns in the database table.

If you are doing this in a webapp, `django` comes with an ORM that interacts with the web framework.